# File format for VBA Open pathname For Output on mac

Tags: macos, vba

When using the VBA Open statement for writing text to a file on a Mac, is the file format ASCII or UNICODE?

Comment: both should just work both fine.

Comment: Um... Couldn't you just take a couple of minutes to test this? Write code to use ASCII, try it to make sure it works, and then change the output to Unicode and see if it still works? (Or, if you prefer, write the Unicode first and then switch to ASCII. Either way, still a couple of minutes.)

Comment: There isn't anyway I can see to specify unicode or ASCII. Is it a system default or something I'm missing?